# How to put a figure in one column and its caption in another column in a two column article latex

Tags: floats, captions

Could some one help me to figure this issue out? I have a two column article and I have figures that are long. They fit in one column and that's ok but if I want to add the caption under the figure, the tex will be too large and does not fit in that column. Is there a way to put the figure in one column and the caption in front of it in the other column?! I tried different things such as figure* or floatrow but that does not give me what I want.

```
   \begin{figure}[!p] %the figure is as long as a column in a two column page
   \begin{center} 
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure3.png} 
   \caption{(Color online) a very long text, as long as a column in a two   column page} 
   \end{center} 
   \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.47\linewidth}
    \null
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=8cm]{example}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.47\textwidth}
    \caption{\protect\lipsum[3] }
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The `\null` is to give the minipage an anchor for alignment, this is only needed if you want `[t]` alignment.

Comment: Thanks, this is working but then instead of my figures I get a black box and lots of text looking like: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,...

Comment: Hm, ok. Remove the `[demo]` from `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Probably remove `,height=8cm`. Remove `\usepackage{lipsum}`.  Write your caption text inside `\caption` instead of `\protect\lipsum[3]`. Write your main text instead of the last `\lipsum`.